# Card widget being cut-off at the end on ios simulator

Tags: ios, flutter, flutter-layout

Card widget (colored in yellow) is being cut-off at the end on iOS simulator, whereas it displays properly on Android emulator, as shown below:

**iOS:**

[image]

**Android**

[image]

**Code to render card widget is:**

```
Widget _editButton() {
    return new Container(
        padding: new EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
        child: new Column(
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
            children: <Widget>[
              Card(
                color: Colors.yellow,
                  elevation: 2.0,
                  child: FlatButton(
                    splashColor: Colors.greenAccent,
                    onPressed: () {},
                  ))
            ]));
  }
```

How to align the card so as to make it consistent (like on Android)?

**Android emulator:** Nexus 6P (1440 x 2560: 560dpi)

**iOS simulator:** iPhone 8

Comment: Try - Wrap your Container in `SafeArea` Widget - https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/SafeArea-class.html

Comment: That didn't work @anmol.majhail. I still see same behavior. I did like this:  `return new SafeArea(
        right: true,
        child: Container(
        padding: new EdgeInsets.all(10.0)`

Answer (score 0):

I resolved it by setting `width` of `Positioned` widget inside `Stack` to :

MediaQuery.of(context).size.width